# Mobile App Authentication with Web Api using Azure Ad B2C using Our own Login View for Signin

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a mobile app (native) that has been added as an application in my Azure AD B2C Tenant.

I have a web api (app/api) that has been added as an application in my Azure AD B2C Tenant. I set the mobile app to have access permissions to the web api.

I have set up 2 user flows (not sure they are necessary): 1. User_Auth, 2. Sign_in

I have users that have been added to my AD B2C Tenant using the Azure Graph Client. (This is working.)

When a user logs into the mobile app (with AD B2C credentials) using my own login page, how do I authorize and get the necessary token to authenticate my web api.

I have seen questions that seem similar, but never a response that solves my question. Thanks.

Comment: See similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364881/how-to-connect-with-mobile-application-to-ad-b2c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following sample can be used for mobile apps. 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-msal

If you want to use your custom login screen only, then you will need to setup [ROPC user flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc). Be aware ROPC has certain potential security flaws and is generally not recommended. So a redirection to AADB2C is safer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I already setup an ROPC user flow.

I was able to get an access token for my mobile app using the Application ID as my Client ID.

That token doesn't work when I attempt to authenticate my web api. I am getting the "Audience validation failed" Do I need to get another access token using the Application ID for the Web Api, instead?

Comment: You can intercept the token and check the aud claim using https://jwt.ms. match the aud claim with your appId. Accordingly accept or reject token in your webapi

Comment: I got this to work. I had to check my audience and I also had to be sure that Authority in my web api matched the token. After fixing both of those, it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to follow this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens of how to publish your app permissions and acquire access token from B2C?