# How to connect with mobile application to AD B2C

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory

I' ve a web api in .net core (3.1).

This web is used by 3 applications :

- Web Application
- Ios App
- Android App

For the Web Application we use the default login page. so after login there is a redirect to the client application.

For Ios and Android Apps we are not able to find a code that worked in order to get the token.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there are various samples of how to get azure ad tokens to call apis. please take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples

pay particular attention to the first 2: ios-swift-native-msal and android-native-msal
they basically do exactly that, with the MSAL library to get tokens and allow you to use it to call web apis.